# Ceci explique mais ne justifie pas

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Ils m'ont dit : « ceci explique mais ne justifie pas ». Je n'ai pas bien compris. J'arrive pas a faire la distinction entre *justifier* et *expliquer* ?

Comment: La phrase devrait être *Ceci explique **cela**, mais ne **le** justifie pas* -- Ceci=ce qui est dit, cela=ce qui a été fait : il y a donc une explication de ce qui a été fait... mais ce qui a été fait n'est pas *juste*, ne correspond pas aux lois de la Justice, aux règles sociales, n'est pas équitable, va à l'encontre de la sécurité, de la loyauté, ou de toute autre qualité requise pour vivre en société.

Answer (score 4):

Selon moi : lorsqu'ils sont utilisés dans cette expression, **expliquer** est utilisé pour l'action de simplement "présenter les faits et comment ils se sont produits", alors que **justifier** apporte un jugement moral sur ces faits et potentiellement sur la personne qui les a commis. La personne a compris ce qu'il s'est passé, mais ne pense pas que ce qu'a fait l'autre personne est "justifié", "acceptable" pour autant.

Serait-il possible d'avoir la phrase complète afin de préciser un peu cette idée ?

Comment: C'était dans une conversation... On me reproche de ne pas avoir bien saisi la gravité de la situation

Comment: une personne peut expliquer ses choix et les raisons qui l'ont poussé à agir d'une certaine manière sans que cela ne suffise à justifier son action (c'est à dire à la rendre légitime)

Comment: Un exemple ; un enfant à mangé les bonbons de sa sœur : "Pourquoi as-tu fais ça ?" - J'avais fini tous mes bonbons, et j'en voulais plus. "Ceci explique mais ne justifie pas."

Answer (score 3):

`Expliquer`, c'est donner la raison, raconter comment ça s'est passé. Une `explication` est normalement objective, c'est-à-dire qu'elle ne prend en compte que les faits. Le but de `explication` est de faire comprendre.

`Justifier`, c'est essayer de prouver l'explication avec divers moyens, de convaincre la personne en face. La `justification` est subjective. Elle veut démontrer quelque chose.

Par exemple :

> - Pourquoi  es-tu en retard ? 
>   - Il y avait des bouchons sur la route. 
>   - Ah, cela explique ton retard, cependant ça ne le justifie pas, puisque tu aurais pu prendre des mesures pour éviter les bouchons -- comme partir plus tôt ou prendre un autre chemin.

J'espère que ça éclaire ta lanterne :)

Comment: Tu veux dire justifier zst subjectif or expliquer ne l'est pas ??

Comment: En effet, lorsque tu te justifies, tu cherches à convaincre l'autre (de ton raisonnement, de la raison de ton action...). Si la conviction *peut* être objective, c'est rarement le cas, puisque elle fait appel à la raison et va alors utiliser des procédés qui peuvent ne pas relever entièrement de faits. Au contraire, l'explication *se doit* d'être neutre afin de préserver la véritable nature de l'évènement et de ne pas le déformer.

Comment: Ca va à l'encontre du sens voulu alors :D

Comment: Non, justement : la personne qui dit "ceci explique mais ne justifie pas" comprend l'évènement et la façon dans laquelle l'action s'est déroulée, cependant elle choisit de penser que cette explication n'est pas suffisante pour, par exemple, accepter des excuses ou adhérer à ton point de vue

Comment: J'ai peur qu'il m'ait dit : ceci jusrifie mais n'explique pas...  Donc ?!?

Comment: Il faudrait que tu nous retranscrives la conversation (même incomplète) pour que nous puissions t'aider plus... Il me semble cependant bizarre que quelque chose soit justifié sans être expliqué...

Answer (score 3):

*Expliquer* c'est donner des détails, ainsi que les mécanismes qui ont été mis en oeuvre, dans le but de rendre les événements compréhensibles. Par exemple je peux expliquer un meurtre passionnel en disant que le mari était atteint de troubles psychotiques dus à un traumatisme dans son enfance.

*Justifier* c'est donner des détails et les mécanismes dans le but de rendre l'événement acceptable. Souvent une justification est une explication dans laquelle on a ajouté des jugements de valeur. Pour reprendre l'exemple ci-dessus on justifie le meurtre passionnel si on dit que cette pécheresse de femme avait trompé son mari et qu'elle mérite bien ce qui lui est arrivé.

Il existe aussi d'autres sens pour ces deux mots mais ici ce sont ceux-là qui sont pertinents.